# How do I assign a language to all datetime outputs

Tags: templating, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I am building a german calendar and am struggling having one language throughout all datetime outputs. The website is set to lang = de but the outputs of the solspace calendar is still english.

Comment: I have now the Intl-Extension for twig installed in order to use the localizeddate filter. It just doesn't work.    
{{ "now"|localizeddate("m/d/Y") }}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kelsey Martens of solspace I found the key. The solspace demo calender uses the .format() method which doesn't translate to the sites language. Now I use the |date filter instead which translates also month and daynames.

Comment: If you are on Craft 3, you can tryout my plugin called Translitedated which allows you to pass a date format and a language/locale for the date to be outputted as. Not directly what you are looking for but if you run into language specific date issues you can try it.